Can anyone teach me about Lemma 25.21 of the Gortz, Wedhorn, Algebraic Geometry Vol.2. ( involving derived functors )?
I am reading the Gortz, Wedhorn, Algebraic Geometry, Vol.2., proof of Lemma 25.21 and don't understand anything. I think that I am begginer of the theory of derived category and that of cohomology of schemes.

Lemma 25.21. Let $f: X\to S$ be a morphism between qcqs schemes. Consider $ E \in D_{\mathrm{qcoh}}(X)$ and $F \in D_{\mathrm{qcoh}}(S)$. The composition
$$ R\operatorname{Hom}_{\mathcal{O}_X}(E,f^{\times}F) \to R \operatorname{Hom}_{\mathcal{O}_X}(Lf^{*}Rf_{*}E, f^{\times}F) \to R \operatorname{Hom}_S(Rf_{*}E, Rf_{*}f^{\times}F) \to R \operatorname{Hom}_S ( Rf_{*}E,F)$$
is an isomorphism.

Proof. To check that the given morphisms is an isomorphism ( in $D(S)$ ), it is enough to check that applying $H^{i}$ gives an isomorphism for every $i$. Now
$$ H^{i}(R \operatorname{Hom}_S(A,B))= \operatorname{Hom}_{D(S)}(A,B[i]),$$
see Remark F.217. Since all of the above is compatiable with shifts, we can replace all the $R\operatorname{Hom}$ terms above with usual $\mathrm{Hom}$ groups in the respective derived categories. In that case we get back the adjunction map relating $Rf_{*}$ and $f^{\times}$. QED.
My questions are,
Q.1. What the composition in the Lemma 25.21 exactly means and for the first statement of the proof, why the given morphisms in the Lemma 25.21 are morphisms in $D(S)$?
EDIT : I think that the first morphism is given by counit $Lf^{*}Rf_{*} (E) \to E$ of the adjunction ( and by taking the $R\operatorname{Hom}_{\mathcal{O}_X} ( , f^{\times} F)$ ) and the second morphism is given by the Gortz's book Theorem 21.128 :

Theorem 21.128. Let $f: X\to Y$ be a morphism of ringed spaces. Let $\mathcal{F} \in D(X)$, $\mathcal{G} \in D(Y)$. (2) Then there is a unique isomorphism
$$ R \operatorname{Hom}_{\mathcal{O}_X}( Lf^{*} \mathcal{G},\mathcal{F}) \cong R \operatorname{Hom}_{\mathcal{O}_Y}(\mathcal{G},Rf_{*}\mathcal{F})$$
which is compatiable with the non-derived adjointness of $f_{*}$ and $f^{*}$ and which is triangulated functorial in $\mathcal{F}$ and $\mathcal{G}$.

( Q. In this theorem, in which category they are isomorphic? )
And I think the thrid morphism is given by the counit $Rf_{*}f^{\times}F \to F$ and by taking $R \operatorname{Hom}_S(Rf_{*}E, )$.
But I still don't know, as in the proof, why it is sufficient to check that applying $H^{i}$ gives an isomorphism for every $i$. That morphisms in the Lemma 25.21 are in same derived category?
Q.2. In the proof, the author writes that " all of the above is compatialbe with shifts", what does that exactly means?
EDIT : I got a feel for this statement, altough I don't show it rigorously until now.
Q.3. Following his proof, let's apply $H^i$ for each morphisms in the Lemma. Then we get
$$\operatorname{Hom}_{D(\mathcal{O}_X)}(E,f^{\times}F[i]) \to \operatorname{Hom}_{D(\mathcal{O}_X)}(Lf^{*}Rf_{*}E, f^{\times}F[i]) \to \operatorname{Hom}_{D(S)}(Rf_{*}E, Rf_{*}f^{\times}F[i]) \to \operatorname{Hom}_{D(S)}(Rf_{*}E, F[i])  $$
This composition is an isomorphism? If so, why? I think that the second morphism is an isomorphism by the adjoint situation. And why the first and third maps are isomorphisms?
EDIT : I recognized new angle. I'm feel like fool. Anyway, perhaps, the composition of the above three maps is actually the adjunction map :
$$\operatorname{Hom}_{D(\mathcal{O}_X)}(E,f^{\times}F[i]) \cong \operatorname{Hom}_{D(S)}(Rf_{*}E, F[i]) $$ ?!
If so, then altough each maps are not need to be isomorphisms, by the adjoint situation the total composed map is an isomorphism. So we are done.
Perhaps, these questions may seem easy in some ways for someone, but I don't know what I don't know and I don't know what facts to use. Can anyone teach me about these questions?

About Q3), I don't know the full context but I think it is cheating to say "perhaps teh composition is actually the adjunction map". It seems to me like this proposition is proving that $Rf_\ast$ and $f^\times$ are adjoint; so it is necessary to prove that this composition really is an isomorphism

Though I have to ask - what is the definition of $f^\times$?

O.K. There ( in the book ) $f^{\times}$ is just defined as induced right adjoint triangulated  functor to $Rf_{} : D_{qcoh}(X) \to D_{qcoh}(S)$ for morphism of qcqs schemes $f :X \to S$, whose existence is gauranteed by Theorem 25.14 (  $D_{qcoh}(X)$ is compactly generated for qcqs scheme $X$ ) , Lemma 22.82 ( $Rf_{}$ commutes with arbitrary direct sum ) , and Corollary 25.3 ( Adjoint functor theorem for triangulated categories ). The Corollary 25.3 depends on the 'Brown representability for triangulated categories', which is not proven in the book.

Should I write specific statement or proof?  I think that the author only defines $f^{\times}$ by the existence theorem and does not define it in explicit form..
